# How to put constraints for a ViewController programatically which I'm calling in a container view?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicontainerview

I have used a `PageViewController` for three controllers with scroll type. Now I have called this PageViewController in a `containerView`, here the issue is the container height is less than that of PageViewController, Im able to call the PageViewController in the `containerView` but the bottom is getting out of the view. I tried to put autolayouts programatically but it didn't work. Let me know how to solve this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        self.setControllerFrame(controller: controller )
        addChild(controller)
        self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)

    }

    func setControllerFrame(controller: UIViewController){
        //Validating frames according to orientation
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        //*******temp fix:******** this is solutions for a single device not for all devices(screen sizes).
        if (self.view.frame.size.width < self.view.frame.size.height){
        controller.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        } else if (self.view.frame.size.width >= self.view.frame.size.height){
        controller.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.height, height: self.view.frame.size.width)
        }
         //tried this but crashes at last line.
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
}
```

the above code `*******temp fix:********` solves my problem for a single device screen but not for all devices. so please let me know a proper solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Below code solved my issue.

```
   var controller: ViewController!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        addChild(controller)
        self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        self.setControllerFrame(controller: controller )

    }

    func setControllerFrame(controller: UIViewController){
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()

        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Inside `viewDidLoad` `frame` isn't yet correct so set it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
controller.view.frame  = // value
```

2-This crashed

```
view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
```

as you should add the subview before setting the constraints

```
self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Sh_Khan, tried 1 & 2 still didn't solve my issue. let me know if you can find any other solution.